# swapCursor() slow: "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter, android-cursorloader, android-loadermanager

I keep seeing "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

Is this being caused by swapCursor() in my code below? It appears so: if I remove it, the above  warning disappears.

I still don't understand why it claims to be the main thread that is causing the problem. I have moved the swapCursor() around into various places such as onLoadFinished() and in loadInBackground() but I get the same result.

How can I call swapCursor() so that this warning doesn't appear? The whole reason I used SimpleCursorLoader was avoid holding up the main thread but its still happening.

```
package com.example.sqlitetest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> 
{
  public static Context mContext;

  private LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> mLoaderCallbacks;

  public static SQLiteDatabase      db;
  public static SimpleCursorAdapter cAdapter;
  public static ListView            lvCustomList;


  public static final class MyCursorLoader extends SimpleCursorLoader 
  {
    public MyCursorLoader( Context context )
    {
      super( context );
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground()
    {
      Cursor cursor = null;

      cursor = db.rawQuery( "SELECT rowid _id, Name, Rating FROM Tune ORDER BY Name", null );

      cAdapter.swapCursor( cursor );

      return cursor;
    }
  }  

  @Override
  public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) 
  {
    return new MyCursorLoader( this );
  }

  @Override
  public void onLoadFinished( Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor ) 
  {
//    cAdapter.swapCursor( cursor );
  }

  @Override
  public void onLoaderReset( Loader<Cursor> loader ) 
  {
    cAdapter.swapCursor( null );
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
  {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.tune_artist_album_view );

    mContext = this;

    String path = "/sdcard/MyDb.sqlite";

    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase( path, null, 0 );

    lvCustomList = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.lv_custom_list );

    String[] columns = new String[] { "Name", "Rating" };

    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.lv_tune };  

    cAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter( mContext, R.layout.like_hate_row, null, columns, to, 0 );

    lvCustomList.setAdapter( cAdapter );

    mLoaderCallbacks = this;

    LoaderManager lm = getSupportLoaderManager();

    lm.initLoader( 0, null, mLoaderCallbacks );
  }
}
```

Here is SimpleCursorLoader:

```
package com.example.sqlitetest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader;

/**
 * Used to write apps that run on platforms prior to Android 3.0. When running
 * on Android 3.0 or above, this implementation is still used; it does not try
 * to switch to the framework's implementation. See the framework SDK
 * documentation for a class overview.
 * 
 * This was based on the CursorLoader class
 */
public abstract class SimpleCursorLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<Cursor>
{
  private Cursor mCursor;

  public SimpleCursorLoader( Context context )
  {
    super( context );
  }

  /* Runs on a worker thread */
  @Override
  public abstract Cursor loadInBackground();

  /* Runs on the UI thread */
  @Override
  public void deliverResult( Cursor cursor )
  {
    if( isReset() )
    {
      // An async query came in while the loader is stopped
      if( cursor != null )
      {
        cursor.close();
      }
      return;
    }

    Cursor oldCursor = mCursor;
    mCursor = cursor;

    if( isStarted() )
    {
      super.deliverResult( cursor );
    }

    if( oldCursor != null && oldCursor != cursor && !oldCursor.isClosed() )
    {
      oldCursor.close();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Starts an asynchronous load of the contacts list data. When the result is
   * ready the callbacks will be called on the UI thread. If a previous load has
   * been completed and is still valid the result may be passed to the callbacks
   * immediately.
   * <p/>
   * Must be called from the UI thread
   */
  @Override
  protected void onStartLoading()
  {
    if( mCursor != null )
    {
      deliverResult( mCursor );
    }
    if( takeContentChanged() || mCursor == null )
    {
      forceLoad();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Must be called from the UI thread
   */
  @Override
  protected void onStopLoading()
  {
    // Attempt to cancel the current load task if possible.
    cancelLoad();
  }

  @Override
  public void onCanceled( Cursor cursor )
  {
    if( cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed() )
    {
      cursor.close();
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onReset()
  {
    super.onReset();

    // Ensure the loader is stopped
    onStopLoading();

    if( mCursor != null && !mCursor.isClosed() )
    {
      mCursor.close();
    }
    mCursor = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use Traceview and find out where your time is being spent, rather than guessing.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks I will give it a go and see what it shows. Tried it on my phone at lunchtime and no warnings appeared. Problem may only be occurring on my tablet.

Comment: @CommonsWare: OK, so TraceView tells me that my guess was correct - 1.5 seconds is spent doing nativeExecuteForCursorWindow() on the main thread. Why on the main thread? I obviously haven't achieved my goal of having the datbase retrieval take place in the background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Methods like `query()` and `rawQuery()` don't do what you think they do. Notably, they do not actually query the database. They merely configure the `SQLiteCursor` that they return. When you attempt to use that `Cursor`, it executes the query.

Hence, in your `loadInBackground()` method, in between `rawQuery()` and `swapCursor()`, call `getCount()` on the `Cursor` you got back from `rawQuery()`. That is enough to force the `Cursor` to really do the work for the query, and therefore that work is done on the background thread.

Comment: Aha! Thanks for that. I saw a getCount() call in some of the examples. The return value was ignored and I thought it was just a bit of left over accidental code - that explains its presence! I'll give that a go. If that helps I could be accepting your answer.

Comment: @SparkyNZ: Alas, there is no `yoYouLazyObjectDoTheQueryAlready()` method, otherwise, we'd use that for this use case. :-)

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. Instead of seeing a bit 1.5 second block on the main thread, I see ModernAsyncTask doing that amount of work.. and no warnings about missing frames. I've accepted your answer - thank you very much for that.. and an interesting journey with TraceView.

Comment: its March 2016 now and it's still happening for CursorLoader. Lucky I found it